# Depth sorting triangles in static vector 3D engine

Tags: graphics, 3d, vector-graphics

I'm trying to write a 3D renderer for a scientific application which is based on vectors rather than pixels. The idea is to be able to output to vector formats, such as SVG, so I would like to keep everything as vector objects, rather than pixelizing. The objects will often have transparency.

At the moment I decompose everything into 3D triangles and line segments and split where there are overlaps. The scene is then projected and painted with depth-sorting (painter's algorithm). I'm sorting by the minimum depth of the triangle (secondarily sorting by the maximum for ties). This fails when you have long thin triangles behind bigger triangles which can rise in the order.

The scene is only drawn once for the same set of objects. I can't obviously use z-buffering because of the vectorization and transparency. Is there a robust and reasonably fast method of drawing the triangles in the correct z order? Typically there could be a few 1000 triangles.

Comment: Could splitting thin & long triangles in smaller ones (keeping a reasonably aspect ratio) before performing intersections help in your case?

Comment: Perhaps, bu I have some very big triangles near some smaller ones. I think I would have to create 1000s of triangles to get this to work and I don't know of a robust algorithm for doing this.

Comment: I had an idea, which is to compute the intersection on the screen of triangles which have overlapping depth. If they overlap on the screen, then I compute the average depth of the intersecting region of each triangle (using linear interpolation of the corner depths) and compare these to look for triangles which are in the wrong order. I need to investigate whether this is sensible...

Comment: Nice idea, you can use the infinite plane of the front triangle and cut thin and long in two...